# Django filter: Searching in User and Profile Models with paginator

Tags: python, django, django-filter, paginator

I'm trying to create an admin panel where the admin can search for a user by username, first_name, last_name, zip_code (from profile model), etc. For some reason, the paginator works, but when I try to search using django-filter, nothing happens. The results don't change and I still see the whole list of all the users.

Models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
birthdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False, max_length=8)
phone_number = PhoneNumberField(null=True, blank=False, unique=True)
```

filters.py

```
import django_filters
from django_filters import CharFilter
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import *

class AdminUserFilters(django_filters.FilterSet):
    first_name_bitch = CharFilter(field_name='first_name', lookup_expr='icontains')
    # last_name = CharFilter(field_name='last_name', lookup_expr='icontains')
    # zip_code = User.profile.objects.filter(author__user__profile__screenname__icontains=w)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',)
```

views.py

```
User_list = User.objects.all().order_by('username')
User_filter = AdminUserFilters(request.GET, queryset=User_list)

paginator = Paginator(User_filter.qs, 10)
page_num = request.GET.get('page', 1)

try:
    User_list = paginator.page(page_num)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    User_list = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    User_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

context = {'User_list': User_list, 'User_filter':User_filter, 'paginator':paginator, 'page_num':page_num,}
return render(request, "admin/listusers.html", context)
```

listusers.html

```
    {{ User_filter.form }}  
<br>
<button type="submit" type="button" style="height:40px; width:120px" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
<br><br>
{% for user in User_list %}
    <tr>
        <td><a href='/edit_user?edit_username={{ user.username }}'>{{ user.username }}</a></td>
        <td style="min-width: 110px">{{ user.date_joined}}</td>
        <td><a href='/add_household?username={{ user.username }}'>Edit Household</td>
        <td>{{ user.first_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.last_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.profile.birthdate }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.profile.phone_number }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.profile.zip_code }}</td>

    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>

    <p>
        <br>
    {% if User_list.has_previous %}
    <a href="/list_users?page={{ User_list.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
    {% endif %}

    {% if User_list.has_next %}
    <a href="/list_users?page={{ User_list.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
    {% endif %}
        <br><br>
    {% for pg in User_list.paginator.page_range %}
        {% if page_num|slugify != pg|slugify %}
        <input type="button" style="height:50px; width:40px;display: inline-block;" class="btn-primary" onclick="location.href='?page={{pg}}';" value="{{ pg }}" />
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is it that when you go to the different page you get all the results? Or the filter simply does not work when you press the Search button? You will get the first problem because you don't send the get parameters needed for the filter.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried setting the paginator so that it fits all the users in one page. I still don't see the search results. I guess it simply doesn't work when I click the search button.

Comment: I don't see the form tag in your template? You render the form and a submit button but I don't see the opening / closing form tag anywhere?

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue. I was working on this for days wondering why it wasn't working. I kept switching things around and all that was wrong is that I forgot to include the <form> </form> tags.